# How can I use asterisk to mask the password?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I try to write a simple program to let user enter password with _GetCh function to get keyboard input, after then using compare function when user input a to z will masked as *, but it doesn't work
Can anyone help me which part am I wrong?

here is my code, thanks

```
.model small
.586
.stack 100h
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC
.DATA

MSG DB 'Enter Password: $'
PWD DB 'abcd'

.CODE

PASSWORD PROC
     mov ax, @DATA
     mov ds, ax
     mov dx, offset pwd

GetLoop:
     _Begin
     _PutStr msg
     _GetCh noEcho
     cmp al, 13
     je DONE
     cmp al, 'a'
     jnae al, EchoIt
     cmp al, 'z'
     jnbe al, EchoIt
     add al, '*'

EchoIt:
     _PutCh al
     jmp GetLoop

DONE:
     _Exit 0

PASWORD ENDP
END PASSWORD
```

Comment: That can't be your entire program, since it's missing the data section and the macro defintions. In any case, aren't you supposed to have something after the `:` for `GetDec`? E.g. `EXTRN GetDec:PROC`.

Comment: Is https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/CMSC211/fall01/burt/SampleFiles/pcmac.inc the `PCMAC.INC` file you are using?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not much help.  Can you be more specific?  What does it do, and what do you want it to do instead?  What have you tried to investigate - e.g. single-stepping with a debugger?  If not, what prevented you?

Comment: `add al, '*'` seems unlikely to be what you want, since it will *add* the ASCII codes together.  For instance, if the user types `j`(ASCII 152), it will add `*` (ASCII 42) and output the character with code 152+42=194, which is some extended graphics character.  Did you possibly just want to write `mov al, '*'` to print an asterisk *instead of* the original character?

Comment: Did you possibly just want to write mov al, '*' to print an asterisk instead of the original character?   <===Yes, the code for user right now suppose whatever they type from a to z and it will display * to masked what they type

Comment: Here is what I need to do
"
Write assembly code in ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE to read a password from the keyboard. Display the message ' Enter Password: ' and echo each character that the user types as an asterisk(*). If the user types a backspace character ( which enters as the number 8), erase the last character typed by displaying a backspace. a space and another backspace. You shouldn't erase beyond the beginning of the password so you need to keep a count of the asterisks on the screen."

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> jnae al, EchoIt
> jnbe al, EchoIt
> ```

What assembler are you using that allows this peculiar syntax? Also, try to use the simpler form of an instruction. `jnae` is the same as `jb` which is much more readable.

To replace the characters from 'a' to 'z' by an asterisk, you can use the following:

```
     ; here you would insert AL in buffer
     ; and increment the counter
     cmp al, 'a'
     jb  EchoIt
     cmp al, 'z'
     ja  EchoIt
     mov al, '*'
EchoIt:
     _PutCh al
```

For your task you will have to keep the originally inputted characters in a buffer. How else could you hope to verify the password? You must make the insertion **before** doing this asterisk-replacement.

---

You don't want to display the message for each character of the password! Put your *GetLoop* label elsewhere:

```
     _Begin
     _PutStr msg
GetLoop:
     _GetCh noEcho
     cmp al, 13
     je  DONE
     cmp al, 8
     jne Character
Backspace:

     ...

Character:
     ; buffer and counter++
     cmp al, 'a'
     jb  EchoIt
     cmp al, 'z'
     ja  EchoIt
     mov al, '*'
EchoIt:
     _PutCh al
     jmp GetLoop
DONE:
```